# Regular Expression image name

Tags: php, regex

I have a site developer in PHP and I would that the user can upload his image and give them a name.
In my input text he can insert character of all type, the extension is jpg but I insert it, the user have to insert only the name.

What is a regular expression for a filename?

Remove space, bad character and other thing?

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit? do you mean you want a regex that validates if the filename only contains letters and numbers without the file extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something simple as

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $name);
```

That'll remove every character that isn't an underscore, a dash, letters from A-Z (upper and lower case) and digits (0-9).

Comment: Fancy but I'd just use `/[^\w-]/`, +1 thought :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern for filename:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

-> ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+: The beginning must be one or more letters or numbers.
-> (?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$: One or more groups separated by a hyphen, but not necessarily at the end.

This pattern will provide sequences that contain only letters, numbers and hyphens and allow hyphen-separated words. For example,
example-image
19-01-24-news-post-image

Comment: No case-insensitive flag? Underscores aren't allowed?

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$ if you want to allow underscores. You can update your pattern like this.